# combinations for all possible values of r in nCr

Tags: r

Here is my vector:

```
vec <- c("A", "B", "C")
```

And, I want to get all the 7 combinations of vec.

```
desired_output <- tibble( ~A, ~B, ~C,
                           1,  0,  0,
                           0,  1,  0,
                           0,  0,  1,
                           1,  1,  0,
                           1,  0,  1,
                           0,  1,  1,
                           1,  1,  1)
```

I tried the following:

```
#install.packages("gtools")
library(gtools)
r <- c(1,2, 3)
df1 <- purrr::map(r, ~combinations(3,.x,vec))
df2 <- per %>% map_dfr(~data.frame(.x))
```

but could not get the desired results. Could you suggest a solution, especially with different number of elements in vec?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Base solution:

```
vec = c("A", "B", "C")
inp = rep(list(0:1), length(vec))
names(inp) = vec
do.call(expand.grid, inp)
#   A B C
# 1 0 0 0
# 2 1 0 0
# 3 0 1 0
# 4 1 1 0
# 5 0 0 1
# 6 1 0 1
# 7 0 1 1
# 8 1 1 1
```

This gives all **8** combinations, if you want to exclude the all-0 case I'd suggest doing it post-hoc.

---

Thanks to comment from Henrik, here's a `purrr` version:

```
vec = c("A", "B", "C")
library(purrr)
pur = rerun(length(vec), 0:1)
names(pur) = vec
cross_df(pur)
# # A tibble: 8 x 3
#       A     B     C
#   <int> <int> <int>
# 1     0     0     0
# 2     1     0     0
# 3     0     1     0
# 4     1     1     0
# 5     0     0     1
# 6     1     0     1
# 7     0     1     1
# 8     1     1     1
```

---

Curious about timings? On this small example, the `base` solution is about 6x faster, though both are quick enough it shouldn't matter. On a longer input, this ratio seems to hold, I got about 6x faster with `vec = LETTERS[1:10]`. Tried with `LETTERS[1:20]` but got tired of waiting so I aborted.

```
vec = LETTERS[1:10]
microbenchmark(
  base = {
    inp = rep(list(0:1), length(vec));
    names(inp) = vec;
    do.call(expand.grid, inp);},
  purrr = {
    pur = rerun(length(vec), 0:1);
    names(pur) = vec;
    cross_df(pur);
  },
  times = 10L
)
# Unit: microseconds
#   expr       min        lq      mean     median        uq       max neval
#   base   789.668   868.152  1023.248   967.4635  1096.962  1388.559    10
#  purrr 45617.167 45960.080 59621.746 54181.5545 78944.986 87511.789    10
```

Answer (score 0):

base R  solution is better but here is sqldf solution for generating cartesian

```
x_vec <- data.frame( mycol = c("A", "B", "C"), stringsAsFactors = F)

sqldf::sqldf("Select a.mycol mycol1, b.mycol mycol2, c.mycol mycol3  From x_vec a, x_vec b, x_vec c") %>% 
  mutate(myid = 1:n()) %>% 
  reshape2::melt(id.vars = "myid") %>%
  mutate(variable = 1) %>%  unique() %>% 
  reshape2::dcast(myid~value, fill = 0, value.var = "variable") %>% 
  select(-myid) %>% unique()
```

Comment: Interesting solution. Thanks, Selcuk Akbas!